# $h(x) = g(x) - (g(x))^2 +(g(x))^3\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the dependency of increasing and decreasing nature of $h$

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Q. If $$h(x) = g(x) - (g(x))^2 +(g(x))^3\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
> then,
> (a) $h(x)$  is increasing when $g(x)$ is increasing function
> (b) $h(x)$  is increasing when $g'(x)<0$

I have tried,
$$h'(x)=g'(x)-2g(x)g'(x)+3(g(x))^2g'(x)\\$$

> ${h'(x){=g'(x)[1-2g(x)+(g(x))^2+2(g(x))^2]\\=g'(x)[(1-g(x))^2+2(g(x))^2]\\=g'(x)\cdot(+ve)\\\therefore h'(x)>0 \text{ when } g'(x)>0; \quad \text{Option (a) is correct.}}}$

$h(x)$ increasing when $h'(x)>0.$
What to do next?

Comment: If you factor g'(x), it is easy to show the remaining factor is always positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need $g$ to be differentiable. Just notice that $h=f\circ g,$ where $f$ is increasing:
$$f(t)=t-t^2+t^3,\quad f'(t)=1-2t+3t^2=(1-t)^2+2t^2>0$$
Answer a) is therefore correct, and b) is false.